# Periodic tasks on every celery worker

Tags: python, celery

I am looking for a way to execute a specific kind of task on **every celery worker**. The exact use case is a periodic health job that ensures various preconditions for successful tasks initialization & progressions (those metrics reported to different services). For example, ensure that a connection to DB can be established.

I found that remote control & inspect commands can be used for that purpose (with some fixed scheduling) but they are not supported when AWS SQS used as a backend broker.

Any idea of how I can achieve that without adding any memory footprint to the forked process tasks? Maybe by starting another thread in the worker process?

Comment: Do you have celerybeat installed?

Comment: Sure, but the default period tasks will be executed only by one worker. I am looking for a way to execute on all registered workers, also, to be agnostic to message broker implementation.

Answer (score 3):

To solve it, I used [Celery custom worker bootstep](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/extending.html). Which upon startup registers a scheduled task that every X seconds omits a health check task into worker execution pool.

This solution is backend broker agnostic and utilizes the customized worker execution pool.

```py
class WorkerHealthMonitor(bootsteps.StartStopStep):
    requires = {'celery.worker.components:Timer',
                'celery.worker.components:Pool'}

    def __init__(self, worker, **kwargs):
        self.tref = None
        self.interval = 60

    def start(self, worker):
        logger.info("Registering health monitor timer with %d seconds interval", self.interval)
        self.tref = worker.timer.call_repeatedly(
            self.interval, schedule_health_check, (worker,), priority=10,
        )

    def stop(self, worker):
        if self.tref:
            self.tref.cancel()
            self.tref = None


def schedule_health_check(worker):
    worker.pool.apply_async(health_check, callback=health_check_completed)


def health_check(**kwargs):
    logger.info('Running Health Check...')
    return 'I am alive'


def health_check_completed(result):
    logger.info('Health check completed with msg: %s', result)
```

Task registration:

```py
app = Celery('tasks', broker=BROKER_URL, backend=BACKEND_URL)
app.steps['worker'].add(WorkerHealthMonitor)
```

Comment: I like this approach!

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this (I will explain how further below) I recommend you to use the excellent Celery [monitoring and management](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html) API. The `status` command (which in a way does basic health-check) is implemented this way for an example, so you should use it perhaps as the basis for your own implementation.

Before I learned about the "inspect/control API" (that is how I call it) I implemented something similar to what you want to do by assigning an unique queue name to each worker. Then your "send task to all workers" would iterate through all unique queue names (say `worker_1`, `worker_2`, etc), and send the task to each of these queues.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I read the status command code, some part of it uses inspect command. Which supports only RabbitMQ (AMQP) and Redis transports.

Comment: Any other transport (except perhaps SQS) is rubbish and should not be used, in my humble opinion.